# free group quotient by its commutator is a free abelian group via universal property

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, universal-property

> Let $F=F(A)$ be a free group, and let $f:A→G$ be a set-function from the set $A$ to an abelian group $G$. Show that $f$ induces a unique homomorphism $F/[F,F]→G$, where $[F,F]$ is the commutator subgroup of $F$. Conclude that $F/[F,F]≅F_{ab}(A)$.

I currently worked out the following:

> We need to define a proper homomorphism $\tilde{f} : F/[F,F] \to G$. By the universal property of free group, we have a unique homomorphism $\varphi : F \to G$ induced from $f$. Now observe that for $g,h \in A$, 
>   $$
> \varphi(g)\varphi(h)\varphi(g)^{-1}\varphi(h)^{-1} = \varphi(ghg^{-1}h^{-1}) = e
> $$
>   as $G$ is commutative, so we know that $\varphi$ vanish on $[F,F]$. Now we just define
>   $$
> \tilde{f} : F/[F,F] \to G \quad \text{ by } \quad \tilde{f}(x[F,F]) = \varphi(x).
> $$
>   It is a fast check that $\tilde{f}$ is the required homomorphism.

Now It remains to show $F/[F,F]≅F_{ab}(A)$. My textbook told me to show via universal property, so I have the diagram

[image]

Can I conclude by saying that for every $f$ there is a unique $\tilde{f}$ such that the diagram formed by $\pi \circ j, f$ and $f$ commutes?

Comment: in the title, you meant the abelianization

Comment: Though haven't learned that word, but yes I do mean that. So are there possible flaws in that conclusion?

Comment: If you are comfortable with the fact that universal properties characterize objects up to isomorphism, then yes you can conclude

Comment: Thank you very much.